# Installing Rhbase package for RHadoop: missing "libthrift" error

Tags: r, hadoop

I followed the instructions for installing Thrift pre-requisites on
http://github.com/RevolutionAnalytics/RHadoop/wiki/rhbase

And I updated the PKG_CONFIG_PATH

```
[root@localhost cloudera]# pkg-config --cflags thrift
-I/usr/local/include/thrift
```

The only issue I may have had there was that you are supposed to copy the thrift library
 "/usr/local/lib/libthrift.so.0 /usr/lib/ to /usr/lib/

But there is no .0 file

```
[root@localhost cloudera]# cd /usr/local/lib
[root@localhost lib]# ls
libthrift-0.9.0.so    libthriftnb.a   libthriftz-0.9.0.so  pkgconfig
libthrift.a           libthriftnb.la  libthriftz.a
libthrift.la          libthriftnb.so  libthriftz.la
libthriftnb-0.9.0.so  libthrift.so    libthriftz.so
```

...so I just copied libthrift.so

I tried starting the Thrift server but I admit I don't know how to interpret the output...

```
[root@localhost bin]# /usr/bin/hbase thrift start
12/10/29 15:51:54 INFO util.VersionInfo: HBase 0.92.1-cdh4.1.1
12/10/29 15:51:54 INFO util.VersionInfo: Subversion file:///data/1/jenkins/workspace/generic-package-rhel64-6-0/topdir/BUILD/hbase-0.92.1-cdh4.1.1 -r Unknown
12/10/29 15:51:54 INFO util.VersionInfo: Compiled by jenkins on Tue Oct 16 12:01:17 PDT 2012
12/10/29 15:51:55 INFO zookeeper.ZooKeeper: Client environment:zookeeper.version=3.4.3-cdh4.1.1--1, built on 10/16/2012 17:34 GMT
12/10/29 15:51:55 INFO zookeeper.ZooKeeper: Client environment:host.name=localhost.localdomain
12/10/29 15:51:55 INFO zookeeper.ZooKeeper: Client environment:java.version=1.6.0_31
12/10/29 15:51:55 INFO zookeeper.ZooKeeper: Client environment:java.vendor=Sun Microsystems Inc.
12/10/29 15:51:55 INFO zookeeper.ZooKeeper: Client environment:java.home=/usr/java/jdk1.6.0_31/jre
12/10/29 15:51:55 INFO zookeeper.ZooKeeper: Client environment:java.class.path=/usr/lib/hbase/bin/../conf:/usr/java/jdk1.6.0_31/lib/tools.jar:/usr/lib/hbase/bin/..:/usr/lib/hbase/bin/../hbase-0.92.1-cdh4.1.1-security.jar:/usr/lib/hbase/bin/../hbase-0.92.1-cdh4.1.1-security-tests.jar:/usr/lib/hbase/bin/../hbase.jar:/usr/lib/hbase/bin/../lib/activation-1.1.jar:/usr/lib/hbase/bin/../lib/aopalliance-1.0.jar:/usr/lib/hbase/bin/../lib/asm-3.2.jar:/usr/lib/hbase/bin/../lib/avro-1.7.1.cloudera.2.jar:/usr/lib/hbase/bin/../lib/commons-beanutils-1.7.0.jar:/usr/lib/hbase/bin/../lib/commons-beanutils-core-1.8.0.jar:/usr/lib/hbase/bin/../lib/commons-cli-1.2.jar:/usr/lib/hbase/bin/../lib/commons-codec-1.4.jar:/usr/lib/hbase/bin/../lib/commons-collections-3.2.1.jar:/usr/lib/hbase/bin/../lib/commons-configuration-1.6.jar:/usr/lib/hbase/bin/../lib/commons-daemon-1.0.3.jar:/usr/lib/hbase/bin/../lib/commons-digester-1.8.jar:/usr/lib/hbase/bin/../lib/commons-el-1.0.jar:/usr/lib/hbase/bin/../lib/commons-httpclient-3.1.jar:/usr/lib/hbase/bin/../lib/commons-io-2.1.jar:/usr/lib/hbase/bin/../lib/commons-lang-2.5.jar:/usr/lib/hbase/bin/../lib/commons-logging-1.1.1.jar:/usr/lib/hbase/bin/../lib/commons-net-3.1.jar:/usr/lib/hbase/bin/../lib/core-3.1.1.jar:/usr/lib/hbase/bin/../lib/gmbal-api-only-3.0.0-b023.jar:/usr/lib/hbase/bin/../lib/grizzly-framework-2.1.1.jar:/usr/lib/hbase/bin/../lib/grizzly-framework-2.1.1-tests.jar:/usr/lib/hbase/bin/../lib/grizzly-http-2.1.1.jar:/usr/lib/hbase/bin/../lib/grizzly-http-server-2.1.1.jar:/usr/lib/hbase/bin/../lib/grizzly-http-servlet-2.1.1.jar:/usr/lib/hbase/bin/../lib/grizzly-rcm-2.1.1.jar:/usr/lib/hbase/bin/../lib/guava-11.0.2.jar:/usr/lib/hbase/bin/../lib/guice-3.0.jar:/usr/lib/hbase/bin/../lib/guice-servlet-3.0.jar:/usr/lib/hbase/bin/../lib/high-scale-lib-1.1.1.jar:/usr/lib/hbase/bin/../lib/httpclient-4.0.1.jar:/usr/lib/hbase/bin/../lib/httpcore-4.0.1.jar:/usr/lib/hbase/bin/../lib/jackson-core-asl-1.8.8.jar:/usr/lib/hbase/bin/../lib/jackson-jaxrs-1.8.8.jar:/usr/lib/hbase/bin/../lib/jackson-mapper-asl-1.8.8.jar:/usr/lib/hbase/bin/../lib/jackson-xc-1.8.8.jar:/usr/lib/hbase/bin/../lib/jamon-runtime-2.3.1.jar:/usr/lib/hbase/bin/../lib/jasper-compiler-5.5.23.jar:/usr/lib/hbase/bin/../lib/jasper-runtime-5.5.23.jar:/usr/lib/hbase/bin/../lib/javax.inject-1.jar:/usr/lib/hbase/bin/../lib/javax.servlet-3.0.jar:/usr/lib/hbase/bin/../lib/jaxb-api-2.1.jar:/usr/lib/hbase/bin/../lib/jaxb-impl-2.2.3-1.jar:/usr/lib/hbase/bin/../lib/jersey-client-1.8.jar:/usr/lib/hbase/bin/../lib/jersey-core-1.8.jar:/usr/lib/hbase/bin/../lib/jersey-grizzly2-1.8.jar:/usr/lib/hbase/bin/../lib/jersey-guice-1.8.jar:/usr/lib/hbase/bin/../lib/jersey-json-1.8.jar:/usr/lib/hbase/bin/../lib/jersey-server-1.8.jar:/usr/lib/hbase/bin/../lib/jersey-test-framework-core-1.8.jar:/usr/lib/hbase/bin/../lib/jersey-test-framework-grizzly2-1.8.jar:/usr/lib/hbase/bin/../lib/jets3t-0.6.1.jar:/usr/lib/hbase/bin/../lib/jettison-1.1.jar:/usr/lib/hbase/bin/../lib/jetty-6.1.26.cloudera.2.jar:/usr/lib/hbase/bin/../lib/jetty-util-6.1.26.cloudera.2.jar:/usr/lib/hbase/bin/../lib/jruby-complete-1.6.5.jar:/usr/lib/hbase/bin/../lib/jsch-0.1.42.jar:/usr/lib/hbase/bin/../lib/jsp-2.1-6.1.14.jar:/usr/lib/hbase/bin/../lib/jsp-api-2.1-6.1.14.jar:/usr/lib/hbase/bin/../lib/jsp-api-2.1.jar:/usr/lib/hbase/bin/../lib/jsr305-1.3.9.jar:/usr/lib/hbase/bin/../lib/kfs-0.3.jar:/usr/lib/hbase/bin/../lib/libthrift-0.7.0.jar:/usr/lib/hbase/bin/../lib/log4j-1.2.17.jar:/usr/lib/hbase/bin/../lib/management-api-3.0.0-b012.jar:/usr/lib/hbase/bin/../lib/metrics-core-2.1.2.jar:/usr/lib/hbase/bin/../lib/netty-3.2.4.Final.jar:/usr/lib/hbase/bin/../lib/paranamer-2.3.jar:/usr/lib/hbase/bin/../lib/protobuf-java-2.4.0a.jar:/usr/lib/hbase/bin/../lib/servlet-api-2.5-6.1.14.jar:/usr/lib/hbase/bin/../lib/servlet-api-2.5.jar:/usr/lib/hbase/bin/../lib/slf4j-api-1.6.1.jar:/usr/lib/hbase/bin/../lib/snappy-java-1.0.4.1.jar:/usr/lib/hbase/bin/../lib/stax-api-1.0.1.jar:/usr/lib/hbase/bin/../lib/xmlenc-0.52.jar:/usr/lib/hbase/bin/../lib/zookeeper.jar:/etc/hadoop/conf:/*:/lib/*:/usr/lib/zookeeper/zookeeper.jar:/usr/lib/zookeeper/zookeeper-3.4.3-cdh4.1.1.jar:/usr/lib/zookeeper/lib/netty-3.2.2.Final.jar:/usr/lib/zookeeper/lib/jline-0.9.94.jar:/usr/lib/zookeeper/lib/log4j-1.2.15.jar:/usr/lib/zookeeper/lib/slf4j-log4j12-1.6.1.jar:/usr/lib/zookeeper/lib/slf4j-api-1.6.1.jar::/etc/hadoop/conf:/usr/lib/hadoop/lib/commons-io-2.1.jar:/usr/lib/hadoop/lib/xmlenc-0.52.jar:/usr/lib/hadoop/lib/commons-math-2.1.jar:/usr/lib/hadoop/lib/avro-1.7.1.cloudera.2.jar:/usr/lib/hadoop/lib/commons-logging-1.1.1.jar:/usr/lib/hadoop/lib/commons-beanutils-core-1.8.0.jar:/usr/lib/hadoop/lib/junit-4.8.2.jar:/usr/lib/hadoop/lib/kfs-0.3.jar:/usr/lib/hadoop/lib/jetty-util-6.1.26.cloudera.2.jar:/usr/lib/hadoop/lib/jets3t-0.6.1.jar:/usr/lib/hadoop/lib/commons-el-1.0.jar:/usr/lib/hadoop/lib/jaxb-api-2.2.2.jar:/usr/lib/hadoop/lib/jettison-1.1.jar:/usr/lib/hadoop/lib/log4j-1.2.17.jar:/usr/lib/hadoop/lib/commons-configuration-1.6.jar:/usr/lib/hadoop/lib/jasper-compiler-5.5.23.jar:/usr/lib/hadoop/lib/jaxb-impl-2.2.3-1.jar:/usr/lib/hadoop/lib/commons-codec-1.4.jar:/usr/lib/hadoop/lib/snappy-java-1.0.4.1.jar:/usr/lib/hadoop/lib/jline-0.9.94.jar:/usr/lib/hadoop/lib/activation-1.1.jar:/usr/lib/hadoop/lib/jasper-runtime-5.5.23.jar:/usr/lib/hadoop/lib/jersey-core-1.8.jar:/usr/lib/hadoop/lib/jsch-0.1.42.jar:/usr/lib/hadoop/lib/asm-3.2.jar:/usr/lib/hadoop/lib/commons-httpclient-3.1.jar:/usr/lib/hadoop/lib/commons-collections-3.2.1.jar:/usr/lib/hadoop/lib/stax-api-1.0.1.jar:/usr/lib/hadoop/lib/commons-beanutils-1.7.0.jar:/usr/lib/hadoop/lib/jsp-api-2.1.jar:/usr/lib/hadoop/lib/jackson-mapper-asl-1.8.8.jar:/usr/lib/hadoop/lib/jackson-xc-1.8.8.jar:/usr/lib/hadoop/lib/paranamer-2.3.jar:/usr/lib/hadoop/lib/jersey-json-1.8.jar:/usr/lib/hadoop/lib/guava-11.0.2.jar:/usr/lib/hadoop/lib/jsr305-1.3.9.jar:/usr/lib/hadoop/lib/slf4j-log4j12-1.6.1.jar:/usr/lib/hadoop/lib/jackson-core-asl-1.8.8.jar:/usr/lib/hadoop/lib/jetty-6.1.26.cloudera.2.jar:/usr/lib/hadoop/lib/mockito-all-1.8.5.jar:/usr/lib/hadoop/lib/commons-net-3.1.jar:/usr/lib/hadoop/lib/jackson-jaxrs-1.8.8.jar:/usr/lib/hadoop/lib/commons-lang-2.5.jar:/usr/lib/hadoop/lib/commons-digester-1.8.jar:/usr/lib/hadoop/lib/zookeeper-3.4.3-cdh4.1.1.jar:/usr/lib/hadoop/lib/commons-cli-1.2.jar:/usr/lib/hadoop/lib/slf4j-api-1.6.1.jar:/usr/lib/hadoop/lib/hue-plugins-2.1.0-cdh4.1.1.jar:/usr/lib/hadoop/lib/protobuf-java-2.4.0a.jar:/usr/lib/hadoop/lib/servlet-api-2.5.jar:/usr/lib/hadoop/lib/jersey-server-1.8.jar:/usr/lib/hadoop/.//hadoop-annotations-2.0.0-cdh4.1.1.jar:/usr/lib/hadoop/.//hadoop-common-2.0.0-cdh4.1.1-tests.jar:/usr/lib/hadoop/.//hadoop-auth-2.0.0-cdh4.1.1.jar:/usr/lib/hadoop/.//hadoop-common-2.0.0-cdh4.1.1.jar:/usr/lib/hadoop/.//hadoop-auth.jar:/usr/lib/hadoop/.//hadoop-common.jar:/usr/lib/hadoop/.//hadoop-annotations.jar:/usr/lib/hadoop-hdfs/./:/usr/lib/hadoop-hdfs/lib/commons-io-2.1.jar:/usr/lib/hadoop-hdfs/lib/xmlenc-0.52.jar:/usr/lib/hadoop-hdfs/lib/commons-logging-1.1.1.jar:/usr/lib/hadoop-hdfs/lib/jetty-util-6.1.26.cloudera.2.jar:/usr/lib/hadoop-hdfs/lib/commons-el-1.0.jar:/usr/lib/hadoop-hdfs/lib/log4j-1.2.17.jar:/usr/lib/hadoop-hdfs/lib/commons-codec-1.4.jar:/usr/lib/hadoop-hdfs/lib/jline-0.9.94.jar:/usr/lib/hadoop-hdfs/lib/jasper-runtime-5.5.23.jar:/usr/lib/hadoop-hdfs/lib/jersey-core-1.8.jar:/usr/lib/hadoop-hdfs/lib/asm-3.2.jar:/usr/lib/hadoop-hdfs/lib/jsp-api-2.1.jar:/usr/lib/hadoop-hdfs/lib/jackson-mapper-asl-1.8.8.jar:/usr/lib/hadoop-hdfs/lib/guava-11.0.2.jar:/usr/lib/hadoop-hdfs/lib/jsr305-1.3.9.jar:/usr/lib/hadoop-hdfs/lib/jackson-core-asl-1.8.8.jar:/usr/lib/hadoop-hdfs/lib/jetty-6.1.26.cloudera.2.jar:/usr/lib/hadoop-hdfs/lib/commons-lang-2.5.jar:/usr/lib/hadoop-hdfs/lib/zookeeper-3.4.3-cdh4.1.1.jar:/usr/lib/hadoop-hdfs/lib/commons-cli-1.2.jar:/usr/lib/hadoop-hdfs/lib/protobuf-java-2.4.0a.jar:/usr/lib/hadoop-hdfs/lib/servlet-api-2.5.jar:/usr/lib/hadoop-hdfs/lib/commons-daemon-1.0.3.jar:/usr/lib/hadoop-hdfs/lib/jersey-server-1.8.jar:/usr/lib/hadoop-hdfs/.//hadoop-hdfs-2.0.0-cdh4.1.1.jar:/usr/lib/hadoop-hdfs/.//hadoop-hdfs.jar:/usr/lib/hadoop-hdfs/.//hadoop-hdfs-2.0.0-cdh4.1.1-tests.jar:/usr/lib/hadoop-yarn/lib/commons-io-2.1.jar:/usr/lib/hadoop-yarn/lib/avro-1.7.1.cloudera.2.jar:/usr/lib/hadoop-yarn/lib/log4j-1.2.17.jar:/usr/lib/hadoop-yarn/lib/jersey-guice-1.8.jar:/usr/lib/hadoop-yarn/lib/javax.inject-1.jar:/usr/lib/hadoop-yarn/lib/snappy-java-1.0.4.1.jar:/usr/lib/hadoop-yarn/lib/jersey-core-1.8.jar:/usr/lib/hadoop-yarn/lib/asm-3.2.jar:/usr/lib/hadoop-yarn/lib/aopalliance-1.0.jar:/usr/lib/hadoop-yarn/lib/jackson-mapper-asl-1.8.8.jar:/usr/lib/hadoop-yarn/lib/paranamer-2.3.jar:/usr/lib/hadoop-yarn/lib/guice-3.0.jar:/usr/lib/hadoop-yarn/lib/guice-servlet-3.0.jar:/usr/lib/hadoop-yarn/lib/jackson-core-asl-1.8.8.jar:/usr/lib/hadoop-yarn/lib/netty-3.2.4.Final.jar:/usr/lib/hadoop-yarn/lib/protobuf-java-2.4.0a.jar:/usr/lib/hadoop-yarn/lib/jersey-server-1.8.jar:/usr/lib/hadoop-yarn/.//hadoop-yarn-applications-distributedshell.jar:/usr/lib/hadoop-yarn/.//hadoop-yarn-server-nodemanager-2.0.0-cdh4.1.1.jar:/usr/lib/hadoop-yarn/.//hadoop-yarn-server-resourcemanager-2.0.0-cdh4.1.1.jar:/usr/lib/hadoop-yarn/.//hadoop-yarn-server-tests.jar:/usr/lib/hadoop-yarn/.//hadoop-yarn-server-tests-2.0.0-cdh4.1.1-tests.jar:/usr/lib/hadoop-yarn/.//hadoop-yarn-common-2.0.0-cdh4.1.1.jar:/usr/lib/hadoop-yarn/.//hadoop-yarn-server-tests-2.0.0-cdh4.1.1.jar:/usr/lib/hadoop-yarn/.//hadoop-yarn-applications-distributedshell-2.0.0-cdh4.1.1.jar:/usr/lib/hadoop-yarn/.//hadoop-yarn-server-common.jar:/usr/lib/hadoop-yarn/.//hadoop-yarn-server-web-proxy-2.0.0-cdh4.1.1.jar:/usr/lib/hadoop-yarn/.//hadoop-yarn-server-nodemanager.jar:/usr/lib/hadoop-yarn/.//hadoop-yarn-site-2.0.0-cdh4.1.1.jar:/usr/lib/hadoop-yarn/.//hadoop-yarn-site.jar:/usr/lib/hadoop-yarn/.//hadoop-yarn-server-web-proxy.jar:/usr/lib/hadoop-yarn/.//hadoop-yarn-server-common-2.0.0-cdh4.1.1.jar:/usr/lib/hadoop-yarn/.//hadoop-yarn-api.jar:/usr/lib/hadoop-yarn/.//hadoop-yarn-api-2.0.0-cdh4.1.1.jar:/usr/lib/hadoop-yarn/.//hadoop-yarn-common.jar:/usr/lib/hadoop-yarn/.//hadoop-yarn-server-resourcemanager.jar:/usr/lib/hadoop-mapreduce/lib/commons-io-2.1.jar:/usr/lib/hadoop-mapreduce/lib/avro-1.7.1.cloudera.2.jar:/usr/lib/hadoop-mapreduce/lib/log4j-1.2.17.jar:/usr/lib/hadoop-mapreduce/lib/jersey-guice-1.8.jar:/usr/lib/hadoop-mapreduce/lib/javax.inject-1.jar:/usr/lib/hadoop-mapreduce/lib/snappy-java-1.0.4.1.jar:/usr/lib/hadoop-mapreduce/lib/jersey-core-1.8.jar:/usr/lib/hadoop-mapreduce/lib/asm-3.2.jar:/usr/lib/hadoop-mapreduce/lib/aopalliance-1.0.jar:/usr/lib/hadoop-mapreduce/lib/jackson-mapper-asl-1.8.8.jar:/usr/lib/hadoop-mapreduce/lib/paranamer-2.3.jar:/usr/lib/hadoop-mapreduce/lib/guice-3.0.jar:/usr/lib/hadoop-mapreduce/lib/guice-servlet-3.0.jar:/usr/lib/hadoop-mapreduce/lib/jackson-core-asl-1.8.8.jar:/usr/lib/hadoop-mapreduce/lib/netty-3.2.4.Final.jar:/usr/lib/hadoop-mapreduce/lib/protobuf-java-2.4.0a.jar:/usr/lib/hadoop-mapreduce/lib/jersey-server-1.8.jar:/usr/lib/hadoop-mapreduce/.//hadoop-rumen.jar:/usr/lib/hadoop-mapreduce/.//hadoop-distcp-2.0.0-cdh4.1.1.jar:/usr/lib/hadoop-mapreduce/.//hadoop-mapreduce-client-common.jar:/usr/lib/hadoop-mapreduce/.//hadoop-gridmix.jar:/usr/lib/hadoop-mapreduce/.//hadoop-streaming.jar:/usr/lib/hadoop-mapreduce/.//hadoop-rumen-2.0.0-cdh4.1.1.jar:/usr/lib/hadoop-mapreduce/.//hadoop-extras-2.0.0-cdh4.1.1.jar:/usr/lib/hadoop-mapreduce/.//hadoop-mapreduce-client-common-2.0.0-cdh4.1.1.jar:/usr/lib/hadoop-mapreduce/.//hadoop-distcp.jar:/usr/lib/hadoop-mapreduce/.//hadoop-mapreduce-client-core-2.0.0-cdh4.1.1.jar:/usr/lib/hadoop-mapreduce/.//hadoop-datajoin-2.0.0-cdh4.1.1.jar:/usr/lib/hadoop-mapreduce/.//hadoop-mapreduce-examples-2.0.0-cdh4.1.1.jar:/usr/lib/hadoop-mapreduce/.//hadoop-mapreduce-client-jobclient.jar:/usr/lib/hadoop-mapreduce/.//hadoop-mapreduce-client-hs.jar:/usr/lib/hadoop-mapreduce/.//hadoop-mapreduce-client-core.jar:/usr/lib/hadoop-mapreduce/.//hadoop-archives.jar:/usr/lib/hadoop-mapreduce/.//hadoop-mapreduce-client-jobclient-2.0.0-cdh4.1.1-tests.jar:/usr/lib/hadoop-mapreduce/.//hadoop-mapreduce-examples.jar:/usr/lib/hadoop-mapreduce/.//hadoop-mapreduce-client-hs-2.0.0-cdh4.1.1.jar:/usr/lib/hadoop-mapreduce/.//hadoop-mapreduce-client-jobclient-2.0.0-cdh4.1.1.jar:/usr/lib/hadoop-mapreduce/.//hadoop-mapreduce-client-shuffle.jar:/usr/lib/hadoop-mapreduce/.//hadoop-datajoin.jar:/usr/lib/hadoop-mapreduce/.//hadoop-mapreduce-client-shuffle-2.0.0-cdh4.1.1.jar:/usr/lib/hadoop-mapreduce/.//hadoop-mapreduce-client-app.jar:/usr/lib/hadoop-mapreduce/.//hadoop-archives-2.0.0-cdh4.1.1.jar:/usr/lib/hadoop-mapreduce/.//hadoop-gridmix-2.0.0-cdh4.1.1.jar:/usr/lib/hadoop-mapreduce/.//hadoop-mapreduce-client-app-2.0.0-cdh4.1.1.jar:/usr/lib/hadoop-mapreduce/.//hadoop-streaming-2.0.0-cdh4.1.1.jar:/usr/lib/hadoop-mapreduce/.//hadoop-extras.jar
12/10/29 15:51:55 INFO zookeeper.ZooKeeper: Client environment:java.library.path=//usr/lib/hadoop/lib/native:/usr/lib/hbase/bin/../lib/native/Linux-amd64-64
12/10/29 15:51:55 INFO zookeeper.ZooKeeper: Client environment:java.io.tmpdir=/tmp
12/10/29 15:51:55 INFO zookeeper.ZooKeeper: Client environment:java.compiler=<NA>
12/10/29 15:51:55 INFO zookeeper.ZooKeeper: Client environment:os.name=Linux
12/10/29 15:51:55 INFO zookeeper.ZooKeeper: Client environment:os.arch=amd64
12/10/29 15:51:55 INFO zookeeper.ZooKeeper: Client environment:os.version=2.6.32-220.23.1.el6.x86_64
12/10/29 15:51:55 INFO zookeeper.ZooKeeper: Client environment:user.name=root
12/10/29 15:51:55 INFO zookeeper.ZooKeeper: Client environment:user.home=/root
12/10/29 15:51:55 INFO zookeeper.ZooKeeper: Client environment:user.dir=/usr/bin
12/10/29 15:51:55 INFO zookeeper.ZooKeeper: Initiating client connection, connectString=localhost:2181 sessionTimeout=180000 watcher=hconnection
12/10/29 15:51:55 INFO zookeeper.RecoverableZooKeeper: The identifier of this process is 15842@localhost.localdomain
12/10/29 15:51:55 INFO zookeeper.ClientCnxn: Opening socket connection to server localhost.localdomain/127.0.0.1:2181. Will not attempt to authenticate using SASL (Unable to locate a login configuration)
12/10/29 15:51:55 INFO zookeeper.ClientCnxn: Socket connection established to localhost.localdomain/127.0.0.1:2181, initiating session
12/10/29 15:51:55 INFO zookeeper.ClientCnxn: Session establishment complete on server localhost.localdomain/127.0.0.1:2181, sessionid = 0x13aad9c16a60009, negotiated timeout = 40000
12/10/29 15:51:56 WARN conf.Configuration: hadoop.native.lib is deprecated. Instead, use io.native.lib.available
Exception in thread "main" org.apache.thrift.transport.TTransportException: Could not create ServerSocket on address /0.0.0.0:9090.
    at org.apache.thrift.transport.TServerSocket.<init>(TServerSocket.java:93)
    at org.apache.thrift.transport.TServerSocket.<init>(TServerSocket.java:79)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.thrift.ThriftServer.doMain(ThriftServer.java:1028)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.thrift.ThriftServer.main(ThriftServer.java:1066)
```

(Sorry for all that mess). And then finally I try to install rhbase and get that error...

```
[root@localhost cloudera]# sudo -E R CMD INSTALL rhbase_1.1.tar.gz
* installing to library ‘/usr/lib64/R/library’
* installing *source* package ‘rhbase’ ...
** libs
g++ -m64 -I/usr/include/R -DNDEBUG  -I/usr/local/include   -I. -g  -DHAVE_UINTPTR_T -DHAVE_NETDB_H=1 -fpermissive -DHAVE_INTTYPES_H -DHAVE_NETINET_IN_H -I./gen_cpp `pkg-config --cflags thrift` -Wall -fpic  -O2 -g -pipe -Wall -Wp,-D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 -fexceptions -fstack-protector --param=ssp-buffer-size=4 -m64 -mtune=generic  -c Hbase.cpp -o Hbase.o
g++ -m64 -I/usr/include/R -DNDEBUG  -I/usr/local/include   -I. -g  -DHAVE_UINTPTR_T -DHAVE_NETDB_H=1 -fpermissive -DHAVE_INTTYPES_H -DHAVE_NETINET_IN_H -I./gen_cpp `pkg-config --cflags thrift` -Wall -fpic  -O2 -g -pipe -Wall -Wp,-D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 -fexceptions -fstack-protector --param=ssp-buffer-size=4 -m64 -mtune=generic  -c Hbase_constants.cpp -o Hbase_constants.o
g++ -m64 -I/usr/include/R -DNDEBUG  -I/usr/local/include   -I. -g  -DHAVE_UINTPTR_T -DHAVE_NETDB_H=1 -fpermissive -DHAVE_INTTYPES_H -DHAVE_NETINET_IN_H -I./gen_cpp `pkg-config --cflags thrift` -Wall -fpic  -O2 -g -pipe -Wall -Wp,-D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 -fexceptions -fstack-protector --param=ssp-buffer-size=4 -m64 -mtune=generic  -c Hbase_types.cpp -o Hbase_types.o
g++ -m64 -I/usr/include/R -DNDEBUG  -I/usr/local/include   -I. -g  -DHAVE_UINTPTR_T -DHAVE_NETDB_H=1 -fpermissive -DHAVE_INTTYPES_H -DHAVE_NETINET_IN_H -I./gen_cpp `pkg-config --cflags thrift` -Wall -fpic  -O2 -g -pipe -Wall -Wp,-D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 -fexceptions -fstack-protector --param=ssp-buffer-size=4 -m64 -mtune=generic  -c tools.cc -o tools.o
g++ -m64 -shared -L/usr/local/lib64 -o rhbase.so Hbase.o Hbase_constants.o Hbase_types.o tools.o -L/usr/local/lib -lthrift -L/usr/lib64/R/lib -lR
installing to /usr/lib64/R/library/rhbase/libs
** R
** inst
** preparing package for lazy loading
** help
*** installing help indices
  converting help for package ‘rhbase’
    finding HTML links ... done
    admin                                   html 
    functions                               html 
    rhbase                                  html 
** building package indices
** testing if installed package can be loaded
Error in dyn.load(file, DLLpath = DLLpath, ...) :
  unable to load shared object '/usr/lib64/R/library/rhbase/libs/rhbase.so':
  libthrift-0.9.0.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
Error: loading failed
Execution halted
ERROR: loading failed
* removing ‘/usr/lib64/R/library/rhbase’
```

Suggestions?

Answer (score 1):

/sbin/ldconfig /usr/lib/libthrift-0.8.0.so

Answer (score 1):

I have written a detailed post on installing RHbase and working on hbase from R on my blog [Digg Data](http://diggdata.in/post/67561846971/fetch-data-from-hbase-database-from-r-using-rhbase)

I hope it is of some help to you

Answer (score 0):

I solved it by copying libthrift-0.9.0.so to /usr/lib/, which seems obvious now but was counter to the instructions on the install site.